# Why different id values in the admin panel's list and object details views?

Tags: django, django-admin

The custom ModelAdmin class is

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'phone_number', 'id')
    readonly_fields = (id,)
```

The model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?\d{5,15}$', message="Length of number must be between 5 and 15 digits.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=16)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    date_born = models.DateField(blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But the values in the id column list differ from those of the corresponding objects:
[List with an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxr3B.png);
[Object's detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OjS1.png)

Why so?

Comment: Can you post the `models` and the view also

Comment: Added the model.

Comment: Does readonly_fields = ('id',) does the trick?